# wxObjectEventFuntion with wxCommandEvent

Tags: c++, event-handling, wxwidgets

why wxsmith binds wxObjectEventFunction in to the connect assignment and wxCommandEvent in to the implementation function?

ie. in to a OnButtonClick

and the compiler raise the warning:

```
C:\..\Main.cpp|127|warning: cast between incompatible pointer to member types from 'void (MainFrame::*)(wxCommandEvent&)' to 'wxObjectEventFunction' {aka 'void (wxEvtHandler::*)(wxEvent&)'} [-Wcast-function-type]|
```

is there a way to get rid of this warning?

Comment: thanks for the prompt answer. It doesn't really answer, I don't want to suppress the warning, I want to understand it, and if I can do something I wll do it.

Comment: WxWdigets event system relies on this, you cannot do something to change it other than not using WxWidgets, you can just suppress it for the event maps.

Comment: But wxSmith should use the wxCommandEventFunction, not wxObjectEventFunction. I wonder if there is a way to change this.

Comment: this question turned from "how to get rid of this warning" to "how to modify wxsmith to update it to latest wxwidgets API", i think WxFormBuilder is better maintained, and up to date with the code generated, otherwise feel free to modify wxsmith source code to do what you want, it's just a single line change in their source code.

Comment: the initial question is: why wxsmith binds wxObjectEventFunction in to the connect assignment and wxCommandEvent in to the implementation function?

Comment: because wxsmith is over 14 years old, while both the C++ compilers and WxWidgets have had many updates since then.

Comment: @FedericoBianchi, you code shouldn't use `Connect()` at all - it should use `Bind()`. Get rid of wxSmith - it can help but you should find a solution that is maintained and can be used right now to generate the proper code.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed and Igor! I see the point. wxSmith is saving a lot of time in writing lines of code for the UI. Do you suggest other similar tool?